# Differences in visual studio settings between C++ and C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, directory

I'm a C++ programmer, currently learning C#. just wonder how do i set the following configuration in a C# project which i usually do in a C++ project?

1)Additional Include Directories (any .h files not in project directory, C# .cs file need add? or just add in project?)

2)Preprocessor Definitions (got such thing in c#?)

3)Additional library Directories (library files directories path)

4)Additional Dependencies (lib file names)

Comment: Maybe it's better to start with some basic tutorial. C#.Net has very little in common with c++. Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/

Comment: SO works the best when you have a single consise question. E.g you first question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2134017/1997232). Since you have programming experience the best way to learn is when course is based on language you already know. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1179697/1997232).

Comment: 1. C# does not have header files. Files to include in the project are added to the csproj file. 2. C# does not have a preprocessor, but there are compiler directives that look the same, e.g. conditional compilation. They go inline. There are no macros. 3. and 4. again, in the csproj file. If you use visual studio it will handle maintaining the csproj file for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer to the following explanation.

1)C# can create a .cs file automatically if you add the program. Also, you can add other .cs file in the program.

2)It seems that C# program doesn't have Preprocessor Definitions.

3)As usual, Additional library Directories should be 'solution\TestDLL\bin\Debug\TestDLL.dll'.

4)Additional Dependencies has TestDLL.pdb files.